# postgresql connection error with qt creator in windows

Tags: database, qt, postgresql, connection

I have a button on my qui. And when i clicked it, it must be connect databese according to connection infos.

here is my code:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setDatabaseName("Assignment3");
    db.setUserName("postgres");
    db.setPassword("password");
    db.setPort(5432);

    bool ok = db.open();
    if(ok != true)
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Connection","Connection Failed!") ;
    }
    else
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Connection","Connection OK!") ;

        QSqlQueryModel model;
        model.setQuery("select * from students ");

        //ui->tableView->setModel(&model);
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Information","This Message box is needed in       order to see the rendered tableview!") ;

    }
```

}

hostname, databasename, username, password and port are correct and my database in postgresql is active with not contain tables in it.

Any help is appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: And what does the message box say?

Comment: "Connection Failed" . Issue is that not having qpsql driver for qt.

Comment: Do you have `win32:LIBS += libpqdll.lib` in your .pro file? Do you have Qt built with postgresql support?

Comment: try `db.lastError().text();` for more information

Comment: QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QODBC3

Comment: You need to build postgre sql driver. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html#qpsql-for-postgresql-version-7-3-and-above

Answer (score 0):

If you are missing the driver (as the comments suggest) then you should look at getting it.

On Debian, for example you would:

```
apt-get install  libqt4-sql-psql
```

On Fedora you would use a similar yum command

However without knowing your platform, I can't suggest specific steps.